# How To Draw a Triangle-Arrow With The Positions of Detected Objects

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a object detection project.

I have my code. And I have written it by following a tutorial. In the tutorial, the guy drew a rectangle in opencv for every single object which is detected.

But I want to change the rectangle to triangle or Arrow.

let me explain with code===>

In my function, I detect objects.
And here I draw rectangle for detected objects==>

```
 cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0 , 255), 2)
```

But I want to change this rectangle to a triangle.(And I want to set position of triangle to above of object.
Just like in these images:::

This is the object detection with triangle
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the thing that what I want to make instead of rectangle:::
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How Can I make a triangle/arrow with positions of my detected objects?
All of my code is here==>

```
from os.path import sep
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
import json

# Camera feed
cap_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame_cam = cap_cam.read()

hey = 0

print(cv2. __version__)

whT = 320
confThreshold =0.5
nmsThreshold= 0.2

classesFile = "coco.names"
classNames = []
with open(classesFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')
print(classNames)
## Model Files
modelConfiguration = "custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg"
modelWeights = "custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_last.weights"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)
def findObjects(outputs,img):
    global hey
    global previousHey  
    hT, wT, cT = img.shape
    bbox = []
    classIds = []
    confs = []
    for output in outputs:
        for det in output:
            scores = det[5:]
            classId = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classId]
            if confidence > confThreshold:
                w,h = int(det[2]*wT) , int(det[3]*hT)
                x,y = int((det[0]*wT)-w/2) , int((det[1]*hT)-h/2)
                bbox.append([x,y,w,h])
                classIds.append(classId)
                confs.append(float(confidence))
    global indicates
    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox, confs, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)
    hey = 0
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = bbox[i]
        x, y, w, h = box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]
        # print(x,y,w,h)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0 , 255), 2)
        
        #cv2.line(img, (350,400), (x, y), (255,0,0), 4)
        #cv2.line(img, (400,400), (x + 50 , y), (255,0,0), 4)
        #cv.putText(img,f'{classNames[classIds[i]].upper()} {int(confs[i]*100)}%',
                  #(x, y-10), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 255), 2)
        print('success')
        hey = 1
            
        
video_frame_counter = 0
while cap_cam.isOpened():
    img = cv2.imread('photos' + sep + 'lutfen.jpg')
    #BURADA OK VİDEOSU OYNATILACAK
    #if not decetiona diye dene yarın.
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1 / 255, (whT, whT), [0, 0, 0], 1, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    outputNames = [(layersNames[i[0] - 1]) for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    outputs = net.forward(outputNames)
    findObjects(outputs,img)
    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    
    # Video feed
    if hey == 1:
        filename = 'photos' + sep + 'Baslksz-3.mp4'
        cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
        
    if hey == 0:
        filename = 'photos' + sep + 'vid2.mp4'
        cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)    
    print(hey)
    ret, frame_vid = cap_vid.read()

#cap_cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
#cap_cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

# Resize the camera frame to the size of the video
    height = int(cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    width = int(cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    # Capture the next frame from camera
    ret, frame_cam = cap_cam.read()
    video_frame_counter += 1
    if video_frame_counter == cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
            video_frame_counter = 0
            cap_vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
    frame_cam = cv2.resize(frame_cam, (width, height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    #ret = cap_vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, time_passed)

    ret, frame_vid = cap_vid.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Cannot read from video stream')
        break

    # Blend the two images and show the result
    tr = 0.4 # transparency between 0-1, show camera if 0
    frame = ((1-tr) * frame_cam.astype(np.float) + tr * frame_vid.astype(np.float)).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imshow('Transparent result', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: # ESC is pressed
        break
    
cap_cam.release()
cap_vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The easy way

You can use the [`cv.arrowedLine()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0a165a3ca093fd488ac709fdf10c05b2) function that will draw something similar to what you want. For example, to draw a red arrow above your rectangle:

```py
center_x = x + w//2
cv2.arrowedLine(img, (center_x, y-50), (center_x, y-5), (0,0,255), 2, 8, 0, 0.5)
```

which should give a result similar to the image below. Take a look at the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0a165a3ca093fd488ac709fdf10c05b2) for the description of the parameters of the function. You can change its size, thickness, color, etc.

[image: box with arrow]

### Custom arrow shape

If you want more control over the shape of your arrow, you can define a contour (vertex by vertex) and use [`cv.drawContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) to render it. For example:

```py
# define the arrow shape
shape = np.array([[[0,0],[-25,-25],[-10,-25],[-10,-50],
                   [10,-50],[10,-25],[25,-25]]])

# move it to the desired position
cx = x + w // 2
cy = y - 5
shape[:,:,0] += cx
shape[:,:,1] += cy

# draw it
cv2.drawContours(img, shape, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

This snippet will give you the image below. You can adjust the shape by altering the vertices in the `shape` array, or look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) to change the way OpenCV draws it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but Can I ask something? How can I make the arrows width bigger?

Comment: Like now it is so tiny

Comment: Yes but instead of doing with arrowedline If I want to use and triangle(not arrow) How can I set the position of triangle to top of detected object

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL I edited the answer, it gives now two ways of solving to problem (new one more complex but should be closer to what you want).

Comment: thanks for your answers, yes you are right it is more complex but I can make some predictions about how it is being made.

Comment: hmm so sir, Can I get the np array of a video instead of creating shapeds? Can I do that.(Video will be played at the top of rectangle again as you done)

Comment: "get the np array of a video" does not really make sense. Also, playing video over video is out of the scope of your question... I would recommend you to search for related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334443/how-to-overlay-small-animation-on-camera-stream-in-opencv).

Comment: hmm, oket I will search for it but also is there any animation property or is there any way to make a top-down movement for arrow....?

Comment: You'll need to animate the movement yourself. It should not be too difficult, if you have the number of the frame in a variable `i`, you can recompute `cy` like this: `cy = y - 5 + int(10 * np.sin(0.1 * i))`. I let you change the values to make the movement you desire.

Comment: Can you tell me a source inwhich I can learn making shapes with np array? Just like you did. How can I learn it?

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL It is just vertex positions, in pixel coordinates. Try to keep only the three first, like this: `[[[0,0],[-25,-25],[-10,-25]]]` and then add the others one by one, you'll understand how it works.

Comment: Yes you are right but; I just wonder, when I take an objects pixel coordinate in a image it doesnt work properly. So do you know the method name if I want to convert an object to np array in a image